# Views Full Pager alignment

Tags: paging

What would be the easiest way to make the Views PAGER text on a view aka first previous next etc, align center in the view?

Thank  you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, Views 3, we added text-align: center to our stylesheet:

```
.item-list .pager {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And to make it only apply to one specific view:

```
.view-id-my_view_name.view-display-id-page_1 .item-list .pager {
    text-align: center;
}
```